# How to update the pagination on MS Arrow Launcher

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I think in previous versions of the MS Arrow Launcher when I swipe up and down to see all my widgets there was no 'pagination'. In other words as I scrolled up and down the page, I could stop it at any point.

Now it appears I am paging up and down. The issue I have is some of my widgets expand over this pagination border. For example, I have a vertical weather app which is 1 grid box wide and 4 grid boxes high. Part of it is over 1 of my pagination and so is the other.

How can I disable this pagination?